# ¿cómo recorrer un excel por columnas y renglones?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

Intento recorrer un archivo Excel a partir del renglón 1. He colocado en el primer renglón los títulos de los campos que irán; los coloco dentro de un *arraylist* y voy colocando, pero intento colocar información debajo de los títulos pero  no logro hacerlo, comparto código de lo que he intentado:

```
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(data.get(i));
    }
```

aquí recorro por renglón 0 y coloco títulos de columnas

```
    for(int j=0;j<=colecta.size();j++){
        HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(j);
        HSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(j);
        cell.setCellValue(colecta.get(j).getNserie());
    }
```

aquí intento rellenar las celdas con valores

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema o dificultad que tienes?

Comment: intento colocar informacion debajo del primer renglon pero no puedo despues del que coloque informacion

Comment: "no puedo" quizás no es la mejor descripción del problema que tienes. ¿Podrías intentar explicar la dificultad que estás enfrentando con otras palabras?

Comment: si claro, no me coloca la informacion que estoy intentando colocar debajo del primer renglon

Comment: ¿Estás agregando información a una sola columna, y esa no aparece? ¿hay algún mensaje de error? ¿Estás segura que `colecta.size()` devuelve mayor que cero?

Comment: si aparece la columna pero quisiera saber como rellenar columna por columna

Comment: Esa es la parte que no entiendo, ¿qué quieres decir con eso? Si no sabes explicarte con palabras, quizás puedas agregar a la pregunta un pequeño ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr y los datos de los que quieres partir para lograrlo.

Comment: quiero saber como llenar por renglones un archivo excel con apache poi android lo he intentado pero no lo consigo